# Is there any way to popup a view with long text when tapping a button on each collectionview cell?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4.2

[image]I have a `UICollectiobView` and when tapping on the cell it brings me to another `UIViewController` with appropriate data. But also as in this record I want to tap to a button on each cell which will popup the long text for each cell.

As I am showing in this record I added an info button to my cell and want to get the right data from my model to show long text for each cell.

This is code for my popup animation and didSelect at indexpath for cells.

```
import UIKit

let collectionViewReuseIdentifier = "collectionViewCell"

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var infoView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var danceFullDescription: UILabel!

    var dataSource = DataSource()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        infoView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        navigationItem.title = "Հայկական Պարեր"
    }

    func animateIn() {
        self.view.addSubview(infoView)
        infoView.center = self.view.center

        infoView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        infoView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.infoView.alpha = 1
            self.infoView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.collectionView.alpha = 0.3
        }
    }

    func animateOut() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.infoView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.infoView.alpha = 0
            self.collectionView.alpha = 1
        }) { (success: Bool) in
            self.infoView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func showInfo(_ sender: Any) {
        animateIn()
    }

    @IBAction func dismissPopup(_ sender: Any) {
        animateOut()
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return dataSource.numberOfSections
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.numberOfDancesInSection(section)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: collectionViewReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DanceCollectionViewCell

        cell.dance = dataSource.danceForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        // Layers
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let dance = dataSource.danceForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        danceFullDescription.text = dance?.danceName
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: dance)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let dest = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
                dest.detailDance = sender as? Dance
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is that how can I implement the button on the cell to popup the view with long text from the data for each cell?

Comment: showInfo is my button and as an action\

Comment: the problem is that I can click to my button which I added to the cell and popup a vie. And also I can segue from tapping to the cell and go to the detailVIewController and get all the data. All that works fine. Only I need when tapping to the button on the cell to show the long text from the model for each cell index path

Comment: Her in my code in didSelect at IndexPath my this line not updating my text for each cell.

Comment: yes it is called

Comment: only this code not works on didselect at

Comment: danceFullDescription.text = dance?.danceName

Comment: I have CollectionView. Everything works fine with segues. When tapping to the each cell the it brings me to the second viewcontroller and I am getting all the data correctly.
The issue is that I got a long data: name, description, images. And I want to tap to another info button on the cell and to popup a view in first controller and show the long text from my model for each index path

Comment: In each cell I have a little text. I want to tap to the info button and popup a view to expand the text and then dismiss. And when click to the cell, not the button, to bring me the second ViewController